# Set a mark on google maps from php data with javascript [500 (Internal Server Error)]

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've been researching for over 3 days to find an answer that would fit my problem, but I didn't find anything so far.

Here's the problem:
I have a php page with 3 select on it, once the user has selected the value on the selects, the page sends those values to a php page through ajax. The php page will take from a database latitudes & longitudes according to the selects, then it'll place a marker with these coordinates on a Google Map. I already have my google maps API.

When i submit the values to the php page, chrome's console gives back the "POST 500 (internal service error). I've read that it could be caused by an error in the php code or by the server. At the moment i can't access to the server to see the errors log so i'm not sure what's going on.

So the main question is: Did I write the php code correctly? because if I didn't, I won't have to bother my boss with the server access.

If i didn't explain my self well, please let me know, i'm not familiar with asking questions in english so I may have written bad.

Here's the php page with ajax

```
    <?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
require "connessione.php";
?>

<html>
<head>
     <style>
        #map {
        height: 100%; 
      }

      html, body { 
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDslqBC-ZEVJMnuN28gf6lkBrfS_MWMJJg">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


        function funzione_visualizzazione(){


         if(document.myForm.comune.value != '' && document.myForm.fabbisogno_totale.value != '' && document.myForm.fabbisogno_coperto.value != '')
         {




               var comune = document.getElementById("comune").value; 

               var fabbisogno_coperto = document.getElementById("fabbisogno_coperto").value; 

               var fabbisogno_totale = document.getElementById("fabbisogno_totale").value; 



                  $.ajax
                ({  
                    cache:false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "calcola_area.php",  
                    data: {comune : 'comune', fabbisogno_coperto : 'fabbisogno_coperto' , fabbisogno_totale : 'fabbisogno_totale'},
                }).done(function(data){

                    alert(data);

                    $("#risultati").append(data);

            });


        }
        else alert("inserire tutti i dati"); //le parentesi graffe sull'else davano errore
       }





        </script>

</head>
<body>
<?php echo "test";?>


<form name="myForm" action="javascript:funzione_visualizzazione();">

              <select id="comune">
                <?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM comuni_new"; 
                $query = mysql_query($sql,$connessione) or die("MySQL error: " . mysql_error($connessione) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query");


        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

                $nome_comuni = $row['nome_comuni'];

                $id_comuni = $row['id_comuni'];

                         ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $id_comuni?>"><?php echo $nome_comuni?></option>

                <?php
        }

                     ?> 



      </select>
        <select id="fabbisogno_totale">
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                <option value="15"> 15 </option>
                <option value="20"> 20 </option>
                <option value="25"> 25 </option>
                <option value="30"> 30 </option>
        </select>

        <input id="fabbisogno_coperto" type="number" value="" size="40" maxlength="25" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">



</form>




<div id="risultati"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the php page that doesn't work:

```
     <?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require "connessione.php";


if(isset($_POST['comune'])){
    $id_comune = $_POST['comune'];  
}

if(isset($_POST['fabbisogno_totale'])){
    $fabbisogno_totale = $_POST['fabbisogno_totale'];
}

if(isset($_POST['fabbisogno_coperto'])){
    $fabbisogno_coperto = $_POST['fabbisogno_coperto']
}







$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comuni_new where id_comune='$id_comune'");


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$longitudine = $row['longitudine'];                              
$latitudine = $row['latitudine'];
//altre cose qui che possono serivire

}





echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'initMap(<?php $latitudine?>,<?php$longitudine?>);',
     '</script>' 


 ?><script>

                function initMap(latitudine, longitudine){

                    var myLatLng = {lat: latitudine, lng: longitudine};

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                            zoom: 8,
                            center: myLatLng
                    });

                     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLng,
                         map: map
                    });
                }
        </script>

        <div id="map"></div>

         <script type="text/javascript">
        initMap();
        </script>

      <?php  
      ?>
```

P.s Just for everyone asking about the format, i'm using sublime text, which gives a proper indentation, maybe with copy&paste on stack overflow, it has been modified

Comment: you know what would help? if you formatted the code so it's readable

Comment: Format the code. By the way it seems the way you use `echo` inside the php code is not correct.

Comment: @JaromandaX i did it, i don't understand; While i was writing the question i put the "put code here" command and as the site said, i formatted it with ctrl+k and i see it formatted so i don't quite understand what you are asking for

Comment: `'initMap(<?php $latitudine?>,<?php$longitudine?>);',` inside a php block???

Comment: seems like you'd want `echo '<script type="text/javascript">initMap('.$latitudine.','.$longitudine.'</script>';`

Comment: @JaromandaX my boss wrote that so i assumed it was correct, if it isn't how can i do that?

Comment: look at the code, at the almost random indentation? is that how you write your code? if not, then you should know what I was talking about

Comment: your boss wrote it? How do you read it? - it's OK, it just takes twice as long to read poorly formatted code

Comment: @JaromandaX i'm using sublime text, maybe on it the code is more readable than on stackoverflow

Comment: It's going to be a lot easier for you if you *do* get access to the server error log. It'll tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Also, you're using the `mysql_*` functions, which were deprecated years ago and have been removed from recent versions of PHP. (a) Stop using those; (b) are you sure your server even supports them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the problems:

```
if(isset($_POST['fabbisogno_coperto'])){
    $fabbisogno_coperto = $_POST['fabbisogno_coperto']
}
```

You are missing semicolon...

btw, just use some proper IDE (e.g. PhpStorm) that has code formatting/coloring and you will never have stupid bugs like that.

UPDATE:

To fix the problem with mysql you must fix your connection script, there is the problem... It returned boolean, instead of a connection/resource.
Here you require it:

`require "connessione.php";`

Another thing, do NOT ever use mysql_* it is very old/deprecated/bugged... just forget that it exist!
Instead use mysql**i**_* or PDO.

Comment: I love you, it's always about semicolons!!!
Now it gives   mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ribionej/public_html/mappe/calcola_area.php on line 31

On line 31 i've got while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))

How can i fix that

Comment: you'll still need to rethink `echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'initMap(<?php $latitudine?>,<?php$longitudine?>);',
     '</script>'`

Comment: @JaromandaX I did it, thank you man. I just started with php and these switch from a language to another confuse me

Comment: @Borna I know that is deprecated but my database works with it and i cannot do otherwhise

Comment: That is really hard to believe, that would mean that mysql is built with that single API... I think all you need is to enable it, I guess you use cPanel, so check there.

Comment: @Borna what i mean is that the database is not mine and i cannot modify anything on it, otherwise i would have already done it

Comment: @TheFiordi_ Well, I suggest you to ask you boss to fix it, that mysql_ API has major security issues, it is really bad.